# Template for formatting output as a dynamic table in bash

Tags: bash, awk, text-formatting, table

I have a created a simple script which is using the ps aux command to give information for a process entered by a user, and presents the output in a table like format (something like the mysql shell is doing for table format).

This is working to some extent, the only problem is how to make the cells fit the content dynamically depending on the value's length. If a value is too long, it goes on a new line and breaks the table.

Is there some smarter way to wrap the value within its cell?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Main function
    main() {
        read -p "Enter the name of the process: " process
        output=$(ps aux | awk -v process="$process" '$0 ~ process && !/awk/ {print}')
        
        if [ -n "$output" ]; then
            printf "+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------------------+\n"
            printf "| %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-100s |\n" "USER" "PID" "%CPU" "%MEM" "START" "COMMAND"
            printf "+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------------------+\n"
    
            echo "$output" | awk '{ printf "| %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-100s |\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $9, substr($0, index($0,$11)) }'
    
            printf "+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------------------+\n"
        else
            echo "No such process found: $process"
        fi
    }
    # Call the main function
    main
```

Current output from above:

```
Enter the name of the process: bash
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------------------+
| USER       | PID        | %CPU       | %MEM       | START      | COMMAND                                                                                              |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------------------+
| userrt     | 1072       | 0.0        | 0.1        | 09:04      | -bash                                                                                                |
| userrt     | 1438       | 0.0        | 0.0        | 09:04      | bash                                                                                                 |
| userrt     | 1575       | 0.0        | 0.1        | 09:04      | /bin/bash --init-file /home/userrt/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28fdety5656bbff2b2/out/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/media/shellIntegration-bash.sh |
| userrt     | 3255       | 0.0        | 0.0        | 11:59      | /bin/bash ./process_monitoring.sh                                                                    |
| userrt     | 3286       | 0.0        | 0.0        | 11:59      | /bin/bash ./process_monitoring.sh                                                                    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------------------+
```

Desired output on smaller screens, something like this:

```
Enter the name of the process: bash
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| USER       | PID        | %CPU       | %MEM       | START      | COMMAND                           |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| userrt     | 1072       | 0.0        | 0.1        | 09:04      | -bash                             |
| userrt     | 1438       | 0.0        | 0.0        | 09:04      | bash                              |
| userrt     | 1575       | 0.0        | 0.1        | 09:04      | /bin/bash --init-file /home/      |
|            |            |            |            |            |  userrt/.vscode-server/bin/       |
|            |            |            |            |            |  0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28fdety   |
|            |            |            |            |            |  5656bbff2b2/out/vs/workbench/    |
|            |            |            |            |            |  contrib/terminal/browser/media/  |
|            |            |            |            |            |  shellIntegrtion-bash.sh          |
| userrt     | 3255       | 0.0        | 0.0        | 11:59      | /bin/bash ./process_monitoring.sh |
| userrt     | 3286       | 0.0        | 0.0        | 11:59      | /bin/bash ./process_monitoring.sh |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please don't multi-post (https://stackoverflow.com/q/77713985/1745001). Copying your question to a different site doesn't make it easier for us to help you parse input when you won't show us the input anyway.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of input I should supply, it's just a name of a process that is currently running on the machine. Can be anything, it doesn't matter.

Comment: It certainly does matter and it's not just the name of a process, it's mainly example output of `ps aux` that you need to parse to look for the name of a process in. It should include partial substring matches (`foo` when `foobar` is present), no matches (`foo` when not present), full string matches, matches against other parts of the `ps aux` output (`foo` is in `grep foo`) so we can see how you want all of those handled and so we have something we can copy/paste to test a potential solution against and get a simple pass/fail result if it produces the output you show from the input you show.

Comment: For example, your existing command would fail if you wanted to find processes named `bash` but a user named `bash` (short for Sebastian) was running a process named `grep` or anyone was running a process named `foobashell` or you wanted to find a process named `awk`, or various other things so make sure to cover all of those in your sample input/output.

Comment: The current command will not fail, it will only show results for anything lets say "bash" related in the USER or COMMAND columns of the ps aux. It is fixable, but that's not the point of my question.

Comment: That is the meaning of "fail" for what you're trying to do. If it wasn't failing it wouldn't need to be fixable. Anything is fixable. If you want something that also probably doesn't work but is fixable then feel free to leave your question as-is and take your chances or if you want a solution that just works then see my previous comments for what you can do to facilitate that. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

main() {
    read -p "Enter the name of the process: " process
    output=$(ps aux | awk -v process="$process" '$0 ~ process && !/awk/ {print}')

    if [ -n "$output" ]; then
        # Print header
        printf "| %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-80s |\n" "USER" "PID" "%CPU" "%MEM" "START" "COMMAND"
        
        # Print separator
        printf "|%s|\n" "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    
        # Print data, use column command for formatting
        echo "$output" | awk '{ printf "| %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-80s |\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $9, substr($0, index($0,$11)) }' | column -t -s "|" | fold -w 80 -s
    else
        echo "No such process found: $process"
    fi
}

main

exit 0
```

Output is passed through `column`, which automatically adjusts the column width.  The `-t` specifies tabular, and the `-s` "|" option sets the delimiter.
Dynamic table layout based on the content length.

Comment: Had the OP provided sample input you'd have been able to test that to see that, among other issues, not including the header line in the pipe to `column` and wrapping each whole line after `column` has aligned the fields rather than wrapping long fields before calling `column` will just output a mess.

Comment: Agreed. This is an actual approach, I figured, being aware of column. It's a direction of some kind, at least, instead of just echo's to awk.